# angular.json styles import and production build files

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 9 for my application and I am not sure what is the optimal way of importing external style and script dependencies in angular.json file.

Currently in angular.json I have the following CSS files:

```
"styles": [
    "external_components/grid/grid-material.css",
    "external_components/grid/grid.css",
    "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
]
```

The first files `external_components/grid/grid-material.css` and `external_components/grid/grid.css` are part of an external grid module and they import image files (the grid uses images as icons). When I run a production build:

```js
npm run production
```

[image: production_build_output_files]

However, the output folder `/dist` contains these files and **all** of the images that are used by the CSS files (`external_components/grid/grid-material.css` and `external_components/grid/grid.css`):

[image: output_folder]

---

**Edit**

The production build includes all of the images used by the grid package. I have shown only few of them in the image above, otherwise the image would be too large.

The production application works just fine with the current production files.

What bothers me is the number of files which are generated in `/output` file.

**Question**

How do to manage this type of files (CSS files which load images or fonts), so that the `/output` file is as clean as possible?

Comment: So the big question to me is, are you asking because the images aren't showing up on your production build for the grid package, or just because not all the images from that package have been included? Production will slim down the app as much as possible, and unused images won't be included (likely why you don't see them all).

Comment: Please check the edit. The application works fine, I just want to have cleaner production build folder.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it myself, but if I remember correctly there is a way to take a certain file type and specify an output folder in your anguar.json file. A good start would be to look for how other folks took, say bundled js files and put them in a subfolder using this. Sorry I'm not much more help there!

Comment: Ah, changing the output folder seems like a possible solution. I will update the question if I manage to do it.